# Print every fifth occurence

Tags: text-processing

I have following configuration in the file. But i have such many configs in the file. I have to print a word which are enclosed in `[]` brackets.

I want to print the word `summary_sai_verbose` only once since this word exists four times and there are many words which starts with summary and enclosed in `[]` brackets and i want to print the word which starts with summary that too only once.

```
#########################################################################
# Indexes Definition for  Verbose for SAI
##########################################################################
[summary_sai_verbose]
maxHotBuckets = 2
maxDataSize = auto_high_volume

homePath = volume:SAI_VOLUME/summary_sai_verbose/db
homePath.maxDataSizeMB = 56842

coldPath = volume:SAI_VOLUME/summary_sai_verbose/colddb
coldPath.maxDataSizeMB = 125053

thawedPath = $SAI_DB/summary_sai_verbose/thaweddb
##########################################################################
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include example output: it isn't clear what you actually expect.

Comment: "every fifth occurence" and "only once" seems contradictory to me.

Comment: Like so: `grep summary_sai_verbose filename | sed -n 5p` ?  I don't know if that's what you mean, though.

Comment: Please be advised as a non-native speaker that abusing "I want" can and will be construed as arrogant and a breach of etiquette.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sai,

Please 
try `sed -ne '/^\[/p' <file_name>  | uniq`

Comment: Does it make sense to use `sed` instead of `grep`?

Comment: Yes, it worked using sed. How can it be written using grep?

Comment: cat file_name |grep -o 'summary[0-9a-zA-Z_]*'. This worked too.

Answer (score 0):

To `grep`:

```
cat file_name |grep -o 'summary[0-9a-zA-Z_]*'
```

add comment if it's you need;

Comment: useless use of cat

Comment: ok, Are you using the full absolute path to cat in the script? The environment that script is running may doesn't have the contents of your PATH variable for your login shell... then try `which cat`, and using full paths in your scripts. For example, instead of calling `cat` you might want to call `/bin/cat`.